# Cannot edit files - "You don’t have permission..."

Tags: finder, permission, preview

I'm having an issue with preview.

I made some .png files on Procreate on my ipad, transferred them via AirDrop, and began editing them in Photoshop. I needed to do a basic crop of the individual layers, and couldn't figure it out in PS. I opened the files in Preview, cropped them, and when I tried to save some of the files, I got the following error message:

> The document “blue 2.png” could not be saved. The file is locked.

With the option to "Save anyway" or "Cancel."

Clicking "Save anyway" then gives me this error:

> You don’t have permission to save the file “blue 2.png” in the folder “design revisions”.

With instructions on how to remedy, and an OK button.

Under General, the file is not locked. Under Permissions, my admin account was "Read & Write," with other accounts (staff and everyone) Read only. I changed those to "Read & Write." and I'm still unable to make changes. Closing photoshop doesn't fix either.

What can I do to fix these permissions errors? It's happening on a few files.

PS - I am the only user on this computer, and my account is the Admin.

Edit: Ran `ls -lOe@` in terminal, here's the result:

```
-rw-rw-rw-@ 2 MyMac  staff  - 89929 Mar 20 16:39 /Users/MyMac/Documents/00 Organize/01 Projects/Auburn /z2022 Fall/Sketch class/ Final Project/Envo Sketches/design revisions/blue 2.png
    com.apple.FinderInfo       32 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS      16 
    com.apple.quarantine   22
```

Comment: Where on disk is the folder 'design revisions'? Is it in your user account? Is it on a server? Cloud folder, perchance?

Comment: Can you do a `ls -lOe@` on the file? If so, then post the output to your question.

Comment: I'll try that, David. @IconDaemon it's on my documents folder... though I do have my google drive pointed at a parent folder of that one, but it's on my drive first, and google is copying it. Should be noted I haven't had this issue at all until the last few weeks (trying to fix a mouse issue)

Comment: Can Photoshop save any other file into ~/Documents? If you duplicate the file, can it work on that?

Comment: @benwiggy  I am able to save both .psd and .png files to the same folder as the problem files. I can edit those files. I still cannot save the file mentioned in the original. Finally, some files I couldn't save this morning, I am able to edit and save. but Blue2.png is still being stubborn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixed

I still do not know what the problem was but it got fixed when I re-installed the OS.